# Grub find FreeDos but can not load it

Tags: grub2

I installed FreeDos 1.3 in one hard and Debian 11 on another hard. at the first Grub does not recognize FreeDos but after `#grub-mkconfig` command and installing grub with `grub-install` and `update-grub` command , grub recognized FreeDos. But still FreeDos does not boot. Following error occurs:

```
Booting a command list
setting partition type to oxb
error: can't find command 'drive map'
error: invalid EFI file path
```

And this is `grub-mkconfig` output related to FreeDos entry

```
menuentry 'FreeDOS (on /dev/sdb1)' --class freedos --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-3423-1103' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod fat
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  3423-1103
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 3423-1103
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seemingly have a UEFI system and FreeDOS cannot work in this mode. It won't boot.

http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/UEFI